# Remove iPad screenshot option for publishing iOS App

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

I am trying to publishing my app in the App Store. My app is only for iOS Mobile. But when I try to added the app screenshots I found there is an iPad option.

[image]

Now, I want to remove the iPad screenshot option in App Store Connect.

I didn't find any solution.

Comment: Is your targeted device in your Xcode project iPhone only?

Comment: FYI, you will still see the slots for iPad screenshots, even if you only target iPhone. Further, on that same page, if you happen to trigger form warnings, the screenshot slots will also show, in brackets, "Required" or "Optional" for each slot. The iPad slots will be marked as "Optional".

Answer (score 5):

In XCode, select your target and select the General tab.

From here, remove the iPad under the "Supported destination" section, by clicking the minus sign:

[image]

This will disable iPad support and remove the iPad screenshots tab from App Store Connect.

Comment: Thank you so much for your support. Your Suggestion was really helpful. It works.

Comment: Hi, my app was being testing on TextFlight and now I am removing the iPad support. I just wanna ask if it will effect my application review process in any context or not?

Comment: No, removing iPad support should not affect the review process

Answer (score -1):

No way to do that without removing support for ipad users

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).